# android cannot use GestureListener on scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview

In my android app, I have a linear layout. Inside it, there is a scrollview that contain a multiple line textview.

I try to add a GestureListener to add the ability to flig left to right to scroll the scrollview to next page, but I find that the GestureListener cannot capture the flip action.

How can I implement above behaviour? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use an `OnTouchListener` instead. It is not as nice, but it does work. Here is one I did earlier:

```
scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    private float mDownX;
    private float mDownY;
    private boolean mDown = false;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mDownX = event.getX();
            mDownY = event.getY();
            mDown = true;
            return false;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (!mDown) {
                mDownX = event.getX();
                mDownY = event.getY();
                mDown = true;
            }

            return false;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (!mDown)
                return false;

            mDown = false;
            float upX = event.getX();
            float upY = event.getY();

            if (Math.abs(upY - mDownY) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH
                    || Math.abs(upX - mDownX) < SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE)
                return false;

            int position1 = position;

            if (upX > mDownX)
                // left to right swipe
            else
                // right to left swipe
                            return false;

        default:
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: this works. But this does not work in below case:
ObservableScrollView extends ScrollView...
I cannot set setOnTouchListener to ObservableScrollView class. Why and how can i solve this problem? thank a lot

Comment: You set the listener on the linear layout, not the scroll view.

Comment: oh, i tried 1 hr again, but still failed. I add listener to linear layout, with a toast to show if it is triggered. but apparently, it cannot be triggered. I guess it is becoz my mainactivity implemented the scrollview?

Comment: That could be something to do with it. As you have probably discovered, the scroll view consumes the swipe event.